# How to add custom tab on home page to track order?

Tags: magento-2.0, shipment-tracking

I need to add 'track your order' tab in home page that will be visible to all but only logged in customer can use to track orders?

Comment: Magento 2 has an "Orders and Returns" link in the footer.

Comment: @ Mat Hellums That is not related to this problem !! I had already gone through it.

Comment: You can track your order from that link. What exactly are you asking if that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

By default in Magento transnational notifications can be sent to the customer by selecting an option while performing actions on the order.

For Example :

Step 1: Your receive Order

The default status will be in pending

Step 2: When you Generate invoice or Shipment you have an option to notify customer if you select that option.

A notification email will be sent to the customer with the respective order update.

Step 3: If both invoice and shipment are generated the status will be updated as complete.

A notification will be sent to the customer as the order has been completed.

Apart from email notifications the customer can login to your store and check the order status

Comment: Thanks ! Joes, But actually i want that button on home page where customer can track his order by putting Tracking Number, which will redirect to courier tracking url.